# ansible playbook to check the condition of Selinux status

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using the below playbook to check SELinux status. All I wanted to do further is that, if the status is not disabled, in the same playbook I need to make the changes to disabled the SELinux status.

```
   tasks:
     - name: To check SELinux status
       shell: getenforce
       register: result


     - set_fact: selinux_status_output="{{ result.stdout }}"

     - debug: var=selinux_status_output
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the selinux module

```
- name: Disable SELinux
  selinux:
    state: disabled
```

See: [selinux Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/selinux_module.html)

**Edit:**
You don't need to check if the state is not disabled. Ansible will check the state of selinux and only if it is not disabled it will try to change the state.

You may want to check the difference between declarative and imperative models.

1. [Declarative vs. Imperative: Two Modeling Patterns
   for the Automated Deployment of Applications](https://www.iaas.uni-stuttgart.de/publications/INPROC-2017-12-Declarative-vs-Imperative-Modeling-Patterns.pdf)
2. [Declarative vs. Imperative Models for Configuration Management: Which Is Really Better?](https://www.upguard.com/articles/declarative-vs.-imperative-models-for-configuration-management)

Comment: First i want to check the status, if it's not disabled then only i should disable it. Please advice

Comment: Hi. Check the links i added to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to disable SELinux, follow @yabberth's answer - Ansible is declarative and idempotent unless you mess things up. Therefore, if you have a task that **declares** selinux state as **disabled**, Ansible selinux module will check and set selinux state accordingly.

On the other hand, if someone's still looking for a condition to run a task based on SELinux state, I'd use Ansible facts. Here is an example:

```
- seboolean:
    name: 'some_boolean'
    state: yes
    persistent: yes
  when: ansible_facts.selinux.status == 'enabled'
```

Comment: A safer expression might be `when: ansible_selinux is defined and ansible_selinux != False and ansible_selinux.status == 'enabled'` as explained in https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/6jo1xe/checking_for_selinux/

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet, but as Yabberth said, you can just use the `selinux` module. 
When your running the play, only systems in a changed state would've been not set to disabled. If the state is already disabled ansible will leave it alone and move on to the next task.

If you use the `shell` module to check first, you'll always see the changed state since its registering it into the job flow. If your running a check check first and then change afterwards, it might be a bit overkill considering the `selinux` module will do what your asking IMO.

Comment: To add to this, when using the `selinux` module, if you want to check first before making changes, use `--check`and `--diff` when executing the playbook.
`ansible-playbook -b selinux.yml --check --diff` 
this will allow you to run the playbook, see what is not in a disabled state, and will not make actual changes to the file.

Comment: What @user2246706 said x 1000.  Try to shift your thinking about Ansible from "check the state and change it if it is incorrect" to "here is the state I want the service to be in".  Ansible modules will always check the state if possible, and make the change ONLY if a change is needed.  Don't overcomplicate your task by trying to use Ansible like a traditional programming language.

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where you may still wish to test whether SELinux is enabled. For instance, the Ansible module `sefcontext` generates a failure message, if SELinux is disabled. E.g.:

```
TASK [users : Set SELinux context of directory /foo/bar to ftpd_u] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [172.16.1.76]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "SELinux is disabled on this host."}
```

To test whether SELinux is enabled, use `selinuxenabled` rather than `getenforce` (or perhaps both).

Here's an example of some tasks with this dependency. Note that in the first task, you ignore errors, because you don't want *that* task to fail based on the exit code of `selinuxenabled`.

```
- name: Test whether SELinux is enabled
  command: /usr/sbin/selinuxenabled
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: selinux_status

- name: Set SELinux context of custom ftp directory /foo/bar to ftpd_u if SE Linux is enabled
  sefcontext:
    target: /foo/bar
    setype: ftpd_u
    state: present
  register: ftp_dir
  when: selinux_status.rc == 0

- name: Apply new SELinux context for custom FTP directory
  command: restorecon -irv /foo/bar
  when: ftp_dir.changed
```